# ActionScript 3.0 compiler macro to create string of current AS file and code Line?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, compiler-construction, macros

i'd like to do something like this:

```
try{
    operationThatMayFail();
}
catch(e:Error){
    handleError();
    MyLogFileLogger.writeEntry("Error ocurred in file " + CURRENT_AS_FILE + " on line: " + CURRENT_LINE);
}
```

of course i could hardcode that - but if I then change something about the as file, the linenumbers won't be correct anymore, or maybe i rename the as file and so on. It'd be great to be able to create that string somehow using compiler directives.

Is this Possible in an AIR application created with ActionScript 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the [Error class caught in the exception](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html).  You'll want to do this:

```
try{
    operationThatMayFail();
}
catch(e:Error){
    handleError();
    MyLogFileLogger.writeEntry(e.getStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: yes I know that, but this works only in the debug version. I'm looking for something that works on the end users installation, so that if something goes wrong, they can send us the error log

Comment: Not possible.  You need Flash Player Debug to be able to read the file's metadata and catch those error.  The best thing you can (and should) do, is have unit testing to try to catch errors before deploying on top of keeping a log of important events.  If you have a try catch around a function and that fails, there's a good chance that the function is the problem and should investigate further with the debugger...

Comment: obviously - but if it fails only on the client computer, it'd be handy to have a compiler directive that creates the proper debug string at compiletime